# Load balancer: which solution is more appropriate?

Tags: load-balancing

I have the following scenario: multiple alarms on the internet send information they collect to a central point (central reception of alarms- CRA) which is a server with a public ip address. What we need is to forward this traffic on to multiple destinations (servers on private IPs). We would like to send all this information at the same time.

I was thinking about a load balancer solution (but we want to send information simultaneously) or a routing solution...or even a device which can send a copy of information from one IP addresses to multiple private ip destinations. What do you think? thanks a lot in advance..

Also, if I have to size load balancer which are typical questions?
do you have one/varios ISPs?
which is your bandwidth?
multiple servers?
frontend /backend?
which protocol do they speak?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, design your services. What does each component do? What are the messages between services, is it already REST style over HTTP? What does it mean that multiple backends are listening to something? Can you scale this out to many nodes? Diagram this.

Load balancers proxy (sometimes forward) requests to one of several backends. Message brokers deliver bits of data from producers to consumers, sometimes in a many-to-many publish/subscribe scheme. You might use both components. For example, REST style API messages come in via a load balancer to API servers, which then publish messages via the broker for all interested listeners.

Regarding network design and capacity planning, ask all those questions. Volume estimates and availability requirements come from the organization. Message sizes come from a developer's proof of concept. Use these to derive bandwidth, compute, and storage estimates. And design any high availability.